# How can I cancel Salesforce Send?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am aware that for the regular Send flow scheduled emails, I can go to My Tracking and cancel/pause the scheduled send.

However **I CANNOT** see my SCHEDULED SALESFORCE SEND under the **My tracking** folder!
Can anyone help me out how do I CANCEL this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Salesforce Sends folder in Interactions:

[image]

2. Find the send you want to cancel, check the checkbox next to it and click on "View active sends"
   [image]
3. Check the checkbox next to the send you wish to cancel and click on Cancel Send
   [image]

Comment: wow! ok the  "View active sends"  is the place to go! .. thank you @zuzannamj

Comment: happy to help :-)